# Remove or hide values from lookup

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter

I have a **junction object** *(Employee_Skills__c)* between **Contact and Skill__c(Custom object).** Is there a way that we can remove/hide from the lookup of Employee_Skills__c those values which is not being used on any records in the contact?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can do it through Lookup Filter.

Comment: Hi @Bhawna, thanks for your immediate response. We notice that we need to input manually those skills. Is it possible to filter automatically those skills that is not used in the contact?

Comment: @Bhawna, please take some time to review [answer]  and include some code samples or explanations. Yes and no answers are not very helpful given the context the user put in the question. Try to add the context to your answer.